# How to fill application form with no last name?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, personal-name

I'm trying to fill application forms for colleges in the USA. The last name field is mandatory. My last name field in my passport is empty and all these websites say fill according to passport, but as you can see I can't do that here. The DS-160 FAQs say that in this case I should fill my first name as 'FNU' and my last name with my full given name, 'Arjun Mohan'

Is this the protocol to follow?

Comment: The `Travel` SE might be more helpful.

Comment: I would email the admissions or administrative contact in each college you are applying to, and tell them about the situation so they can give you advice.

Comment: @Oleg: If you write `[travel.SE]` the result is this: [travel.se], which is better.